# Enable card plus onboard video

Tags: video, graphics-card, vga, dvi, extended-desktop

I'm simply wondering if it's possible to enable both the on-board video as well as keep my video card enabled. I have a **Radeon HD 5770** card with dual-DVI for two monitors running right now, but if possible I'd like to enable the video on-board my **Asus M4A785TD-V EVO**, so I can get another lower def monitor running on the VGA for three in total.

Excuse my ignorance if this is in no way possible, or a seemingly ridiculous question.

---

**Edit:** I have had a bit of a brainstorm; I have a netbook with VGA out. Would it be possible to do a remote display, sending a third via LAN for output on my netbook from my desktop PC, which would be connected to the aforementioned LCD TV via VGA? What, if any, software could someone suggest to accomplish this?

I would imagine something like RDP, but where control is maintained at the host computer, only sending display to the client.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, at least I don't know a way.

**But:**

Seeing as you have a 5770 anyway - ATI's 5xxx cards support three simulatenous displays anyway. What about that?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response **Tobias**; That may work under different circumstances, however the third display I want to connect is actually a crappy 19" LCD TV with VGA in, it doesn't support DVI/HDMI/DP. Also, I don't currently have an HDMI cable, nor a DP cable, just several VGAs and the 2 DVIs currently in use. The card has 2xDVI, 1xDP and 1xHDMI.

Comment: You can use an adapter to hook a VGA-only display up to a DVI port. Maybe there was even one with your graphics card. However, you still need to hook up one of the screens to the DisplayPort, as far as I know. But those cables cost some 10 bucks or so.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Tobias - BUT not entirely.  I have a Dell Optiplex 320 with an onboard ATI based graphics card working just fine with an add-in nVidia based graphics card.  3 displays work great.

HOWEVER, I have a NEWER Optiplex 330 that CANNOT support the onboard card and the add-in card - it does one or the other and Dell tells me that won't change.  So I'm left with a final option - use a USB based video adapters - you're not going to be playing games on it, but they do work.  Just be careful.  I bought a SIIG based USB video adapter and while it DID give me a 4th screen, it only supports 1680x1050 (and lower) resolutions AND it INSISTS that the display should on the left (or MAYBE the right) - I couldn't tell it to put it on-top or at the bottom or in the middle.  Other brands exist that may not suffer from this problem.  (One brand - sorry don't remember which - claims to support UP TO 6 USB based adapters.

Bottom line - will it work with your board and add-in card?  NO IDEA.  Try it.  Maybe.  Maybe not.  If not, you still have options (there are also old PCI and x1 video cards you COULD get that would give you the displays you want).